# How to identify group header row in UI grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a UI grid, and I want to give different CSS to my row which header row for group.

[image]

Here , I want to give say blue color to entire row which is group row,(has + sign), also, I dont want a cell template to get applied to it in action column.

I can do condition in cell template but how to identify this row.

I found that , group header row gets class 'ui-grid-tree-header-row'
But not sure how to use this information.

I am looking for something like this : [image]

Answer (score 5):

Use ng-if = "row.groupHeader" in your cell template.
I used something like this :

`{ 
      name: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name',
      cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">'+
          '<div class="yourHeaderClass" ng-if="row.groupHeader">{{do or print 
          something only for group row header}}</div>'+
          '<div ng-if="!row.groupHeader">{{do something for group children}}
          </div>
          </div>' 
},`

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-class in your UI-grid row template. from row.entity you will get your data and based on data you can determine whether group exist or not and conditionally select your class. by setting external-scope reference to grid you can use controller method for you group exist related calculation

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know if there is something like aggregateTemplate in UI grid, which was there in ng-gird